# how to automate installshield6.0 property

Tags: installshield

I am trying to automate installshield 6.0.
I want to automate the Name and Version field under Project->settings->Application.
I am trying to put the values in the fields via command prompt.

Can anyone please suggest how can it be done?

Comment: I wouldn't use anything prior to InstallShield 12.0.

Answer (score 1):

I believe InstallShield 6 stored its project information in INI or INI-like files. Examine the changes made to these files when you change those fields in the IDE. Once you know what it does, it should then be straightforward to write a command-line exe that makes the same (or configurable) changes to any project.

Comment: I think it was an .IPR file along with .FGL files and .CDF files.  Yes, it should be text based.  Wow, talk about a flashback.  Why you'd still use that in 2014 is beyond me.